# Doctrine ClassTable vs SingleTable inheritance (specific for a project)

Tags: mysql, database-design, doctrine-orm

I'm developing an art web where users can publish different types of art: Images, Literature, Fonts, etc.. my question is about the database structure for the `Work` table.

Each work has basically the same fields (id, owner, name, description) but also some unique fields:

**Image**: `image_path`, `album_id (relation)`

**Literature**: `text`, `book_id (relation)`

**Fonts**: `file_path`

What will be the best table structure? Please keep in mind that I'll have `Comments` and other relational tables pointing to `Work`

### Single Table Inheritance

**Pros**:
easy to manage and use in relation. No JOINS are required.

**Cons**:
no seperation of the unique fields (FontWork will have `book_id`, `album_id`, etc)

### Class Table Inheritance

**Pros**:
each table will have only it's unique fields.

**Cons**:
[Performance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#id4). multiple JOINS for about every query executed.

I would like to hear your opinion about it and also get new implementation ideas!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you start with simple Single Table inheritance because your classes have few fields, along with a type attribute (a tiny integer) to separate the different entities.

This also means that your comments and work tables will join to one table. As the numbers grow you can partition your table to improve performance.

Bottom line is start simple and make more complex as your needs change.